# Fallback mechanism private repository npm/yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

**What I am trying to achieve?**

Mimic the behavior of Maven with yarn or npm.

I have an application made of two parts **A** a library and **B** the frontend, **B** depends of **A**. I declared the dependency in `package.json` of **B**. When I develop on **A** I would like my changes affect **B** without to publish **A** on the private repository but instead use the local "repository" (`yarn link`). But if the link does not exist the **A** should be fetch from the private repository.

My intuition on this is the following mapping should be possible.

- `yarn link` <~> `mvn install`
- `yarn publish` <~> `mvn deploy`

I don't know if this mechanism is even possible with yarn or npm.
Any insights are welcome.

Comment: I'm experimenting with [Verdaccio](http://www.verdaccio.org/). I'll post my findings in this thread.